# Android studio networking fails

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I am trying to write an app for android but am not able to connect to the website. the website is
[here](https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0). I am able to connect to the website in Firefox and chrome. I wrote a simple program in java SE and it is able to connect to the website. here is the code.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class urltest {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL ( "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0" );
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() ) );
        String line;
        while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null ) 
            System.out.println( line );
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

This program does work and does connect to the website. the android app however does not. here is the manifest file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ledorianindustries.rss2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Rss2">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and here is the MainActivity.

```
package com.ledorianindustries.rss2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new rss().execute();
    }

    public class rss extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Exception> {

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0");
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() ) );
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("info", line);
                }
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("info", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

for reasons that I cannot identify I am presented with the error:

```
2021-02-16 12:19:59.363 13978-14006/com.ledorianindustries.rss2 E/info: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0
```

I have checked to see if google is using their own implementation of the networking stack and as far as I can tell they have not. So then why does it work in java SE but not in android? I would appreciate some help on this matter.

***edit 1
the code for URLConnection will follow.

```
URL url = new URL("https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0");
                //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( url.openStream() ) );
                URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( uc.getInputStream() ) );
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.e("info", line);
                }
                reader.close();
```

the error code is:

```
2021-02-16 14:12:28.132 14638-14698/com.ledorianindustries.rss2 E/info: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0
```

***edit2
I have tried a few other urls:

```
URL url1 = new URL("https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/mn.php?x=0");
URL url2 = new URL("https://www.rediff.com/rss/moviesreviewsrss.xml");
URL url3 = new URL("https://www.cinemablend.com/rss_review.php");
```

url1 is the original url. url2 and url3 work. I am starting to think the "?x=0" may be the problem? I don't know much about php but is that maybe the issue? can php be rewritten? I tried to remove that part in my browser, it was very unhappy.

Comment: Can you use URL#openConnection? What is the status code?

Comment: @dan1st The `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is `HttpURLConnection`'s way of saying 404. Using `openConnection()` rather than `openStream()` won't make any difference.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I can get to the site from both of my browsers and from the java se program. do you have any idea why one would work but not the other?

Comment: Are you sure that the URL is correct? 404 means that the path is not found. I told you to use openStream only because you needed it for the status code.

Comment: you can go to the website. I put the link in the post and the url is in the code. it is a valid working site. it is php and I think that may be part of the problem. were you able to run the code?